# Hiding access to a parent's property in the subclass

Tags: ios, swift, oop

I feel like this should be relatively simple but I can't find a way to accomplish it.

Let say I have

```
class Parent {
   public var file: PFFile?
}
```

and a subclass

```
class Child : Parent {
    // some functionality that hides access to super.file
}
```

Problem is **I can't mess with the Parent class**, but I don't want anyone using the Child class to have access to 'file'. How can I accomplish this in Swift?

Comment: Removing `public` modifier ?

Comment: I can't modify the parent class unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this one fix it:

```
class Parent {
   public var file: PFFile?
}

class RestrictedParent : Parent {
   private override var file: PFFile?
}

class Child : RestrictedParent {
    // some functionality that hides access to super.file
}
```

Here in `RestrictedParent`, we can hide any functionality that should not be visible to any of the child class inheriting to it.

**EDIT**:

A [part from doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html):

```
class Car: Vehicle {
    var gear = 1
    override var description: String {
        return super.description + " in gear \(gear)"
    }
}
```

Comment: did you ever try to override stored property?

Comment: you override computed property, not stored property

Comment: @user3441734, You can override a stored property, but the override itself must be a computed property.  @NeverHopeless, The `Parent`, `RestrictedParent`, `Child` example doesn't compile because the override is a stored property.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html)

> You can prevent a method, property, or subscript from being overridden
>   by marking it as final. Do this by writing the final modifier before
>   the method, property, or subscript’s introducer keyword (such as final
>   var, final func, final class func, and final subscript).

so you can declare parent class as

```
class Parent {
   final var file: PFFile?
}
```

Or if you cannot modify parent class then maybe this would work

```
class Child : Parent {
   override private final var file: PFFile?
}
```

Comment: The `class Child : Parent` example won't compile because the override needs to be a computed property.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is directly possible in Swift 3.  Here is the best workaround I could come up with:

```
class Child : Parent {
    override public var file: PFFile? {
        get { return nil }
        set { }
    }
    func exampleFunction() {
        print(super.PFFile?.description)  // Use like this
        print(PFFile?.description)        // Don't do this
        //This ^^^ will ALWAYS return nil for PFFile
    }
}
```

This is sort of a hack, but it does almost exactly what you want.  It doesn't completely hide the variable from the outside world, but it makes it impotent.  When you try and access `file` you always get `nil`, and when you try and assign a value to file it just does nothing.  So the outside world still knows that `Child` has a property `file` of type `PFFile?`, but it just can't do anything about it.

Essentially, `file` is like an attractive movie star.  You can send them letters, post on their facebook wall, comment on their instagram feed, but they will never reply to you.  You know who they are, and what they look like, but you just can't do anything about it.

Then, inside `Child` you **MUST** use `super.file` **EVERYWHERE** you access `Parent`'s `file` property.  If you use `file` or `self.file` you will be trying to interact with the impotent version, and you will do nothing and get nothing every time!  I have included `exampleFunction()` as an example of this usage.  (I made up the `description` property on `PFFile`, just assume it is a `String`)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `final` modifier，like this :

```
class Perent {
    final var file: PFFile?
}    

class Child: Perent {
    // code here ...
}
```

Comment: He can't modify the parent class